# ASP.NET C# TagBuilder SetInnerText rendered %20 on whitespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me figure it out on this code, i want to build Common Html using TagBuilder with this code.

```
var href = new TagBuilder("a");
href.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
href.SetInnerText(item); <== This part rendered eg. "Just%20Test" but my text "Just Test"
```

i need your help to show "Just Test" because my text has white space.
i already try with Regular Expression but in my page always display like that if have white space.

Thank's in advice, and really sorry for my poor English.

Comment: What is 'item' referring to?  Showing the rest of the code will make it easier on us.

Comment: @macoms01, thanks for your respone, the items refereing to svn url repository eg. https://my-laptop/svn/dm/Manual Book/Just Test

Comment: Does URL decoding work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx? Try decoding item when you set the inner text.

Comment: Where does `item` come from? Does the same result occur is using the [purported] string literal *directly* in that call? I would be really surprised if `SetInnerText` was "smart" enough to apply [Percent Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which should only be done on the actual URL in the href attribute. Thus my hypothesis is the value was somehow introduced prior, or incorrectly observed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
href.InnertHtml = item;
```

in stead. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.setinnertext(v=vs.111).aspx), this will set the inner text without HTML encoding it first.

The funny thing is HTML encoding doesn't encode spaces... but I'm guessing there is more to the problem than your description. This might provide us with more information.